# What is the root of $a(x) = 1 + x^r - 2(x-1)^r$?

Tags: roots

I have been working on my thesis and I have stumble upon the following equation that is giving me a tough time:
$$a(x) = 1 + x^r - 2(x-1)^r$$

What is the root of this equation? As in, for what values of $x$ will $a(x) = 0$? Is there a unique root?
There are a couple of constraints:

- $x \geq 1$
- $r \geq 2$

The constraint on $r$ is not so serious however, though I doubt "pretty" solutions will arise if $p < 1$.

I plotted this function into Mathematica and came out with a curve which is not monotonic with $x$, thus making it difficult to prove the existence of a unique root.

I have tried to take the derivative of the function in order to evaluate for critical points. I seem to be getting $x = \dfrac{2^{1/(r-1)}}{2^{1/(r-1)}-1}$ but this is not it. When I plug-in this critical point into the original equation, it does not equal to zero.

To my knowledge and skills, I feel stumped.

Comment: You already know that the equation has only one root. When you say **the** root, you implicitely assume that there is only one. So, if you have doubts about this, then maybe replace "the root" by "the roots".

Comment: I think that I made some interesting improvements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Another approach*

Let $y=\cosh^2(z)$ (that is to say $x=\coth ^2(z)$) and consider now that we need to find the zero of function
$$g(z)=\log\Big[\sinh ^{2 r}(z)+\cosh ^{2 r}(z)\Big]-\log(2)$$ which is very close to linearity.

Using one single iteration of halley method with
$$z_0=\tanh ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2 \log (2)}{2 r+\log (2)}}\right)\implies 
z_1=z_0- \frac {2 \,g(z_0)\, g'(z_0)} {2 \,{[g'(z_0)]}^2 - g(z_0)\, g''(z_0)}$$

Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
r & z_1 & \text{solution} \\
 10 & \color{red}{0.264800234264}95279706 & 
                  0.26480023426440294083 \\
 20 & \color{red}{0.186702998748}20460378 & 
                  0.18670299874819865061 \\
 30 & \color{red}{0.15229581653017}421982 & 
                  0.15229581653017379595 \\
 40 & \color{red}{0.131828617848412}35565 & 
                  0.13182861784841229053 \\
 50 & \color{red}{0.1178770690152299}6479 & 
                  0.11787706901522994955 \\
 60 & \color{red}{0.10758584167182339}878 & 
                  0.10758584167182339413 \\
 70 & \color{red}{0.09959144191558136}447 & 
                  0.09959144191558136276 \\
 80 & \color{red}{0.09314965796552352}962 & 
                  0.09314965796552352891 \\
 90 & \color{red}{0.087815296380881823}72 & 
                  0.08781529638088182339 \\
 100 & \color{red}{0.083303559678972018}36 & 
                   0.08330355967897201819
\end{array}
\right)$$

You may suppose that this is *my* prefered solution.

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and definitely my favorite of your solutions.

Comment: @CobaltDev. I am quite happy of this formulation in terms of hyperbolic functions. But, guess what ? I am still trying to improve it. Cheers :-)

Comment: You're very gracious, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the equation, my *intuition* was that the solution $x_*$ will be linear with $r$. This has been checked by a contour plot of $a(x)=0$ for $1\leq x \leq 100$ and $2\leq r \leq 100$.

A few calculations
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
r & x_* \\
 10 & 14.9327 \\
 20 & 29.3568 \\
 30 & 43.7828 \\
 40 & 58.2092 \\
 50 & 72.6359 \\
 60 & 87.0627 \\
 70 & 101.489 \\
 80 & 115.916 \\
 90 & 130.343 \\
 100 & 144.770
\end{array}
\right)$$ A quick and dirty linear regression gives with $R^2>0.999999$
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 \alpha & 0.50404 & 0.000730 & \{0.50232,0.50577\} \\
 \beta  & 1.44265 & 0.000012 & \{1.44262,1.44268\} \\
\end{array}$$

Extrapolated for $r=1000$, this gives $x_*=1443.16$ while the solution is $1443.20$.

There is another (very small) root.

In any manner, ^$$a'(x)=0 \implies \left(\frac{x}{x-1}\right)^{r-1}=2 \implies x_{\text{max}}=\frac{2^{\frac{1}{r-1}}}{2^{\frac{1}{r-1}}-1}$$ and $x_* >x_{\text{max}}$.

For large $r$
$$x_{\text{max}}=\frac{r}{\log (2)}+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\log (2)}\right)+\frac{\log (2)}{12r}+\frac{\log (2)}{12 r^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{r^3}\right)$$ For $r=1000$, this gives $x_{\text{max}}=1441.75$ (quite close to the solution).

If you want to numerically solve, use Newton method with $x_0$ given by the empirical correlation. For example, for $r=10000$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 14427.0000000000 \\
 1 & 14427.6548458823 \\
 2 & 14427.4757848783 \\
 3 & 14427.4508530546 \\
 4 & 14427.4504147990 \\
 5 & 14427.4504146659 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Notice that $\beta \sim \frac 1{\log(2)}$ given in the expansion. So, the simplest approximation is
$$x_*=\frac 12 +\frac r{\log(2)} $$

**Edit**

The last proposed approximation can be improved. Let
$$x_*=\frac 12 +\frac r{\log(2)}+\epsilon(r) $$ Expand $a(x)$ as a series up to $O\left(\epsilon ^2\right)$ and use series reversion to obtain
$$\epsilon(r)=\frac{1}{2 r \log (2)} \, \frac{\log ^r(4)-2 (2 r-\log (2))^r+(2 r+\log (2))^r}{2 (2 r-\log (2))^{r-1}-(2
   r+\log (2))^{r-1}}$$ For the case where $r=10000$ looked at just before end, this would give as an estimate
$x=14427.4504146659$ which is the solution.

Trying with $r=2^k$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & \color{red}{3.7}754225843653752403 & 
                 3.7320508075688772935 \\
 2 & \color{red}{6.290}7262317521153027 & 
                 6.2905203826719496086 \\
 3 & \color{red}{12.048}811554320985251 & 
                 12.048779744481548435 \\
 4 & \color{red}{23.58673}9175499452336 &  
                 23.586730682870478481 \\
 5 & \color{red}{46.66804}8555883121630 &
                 46.668046365114270141 \\
 6 & \color{red}{92.833385}706672057396 & 
                 92.833385150520588998 \\
 7 &\color{red}{ 185.165416}64135828893 & 
                 185.16541650126243983 \\
 8 & \color{red}{369.8301561}3655115031 & 
                 369.83015610139490248 \\
 9 & \color{red}{739.1599737}6087533816 & 
                 739.15997375206973774 \\
 10 & \color{red}{1477.8197782}809635256 & 
                  1477.8197782787600580 \\
 11 & \color{red}{2955.13947194}53791096 &  
                  2955.1394719448279842 \\
 12 & \color{red}{5909.778901583}4474134 & 
                  5909.7789015833095997 \\
 13 & \color{red}{11819.0577820134}80435 & 
                  11819.057782013445977 \\
 14 & \color{red}{23637.615553450313953} &
                  23637.615553450313953 
\end{array}
\right)$$

This could be still much improved expand to $O\left(\epsilon ^n\right)$ $(n \geq 3)$ but $\epsilon(r)$ would become quite nasty. For example, for $k=2$ and $n=3$ this would give $6.290516793$ which is much better.

Comment: This looks really good, and I appreciate the simple approximation that you provided. If no exact solution comes by I will use this numerical solution. Thank you.

Comment: (+1) Impressive as ever! Two questions for my own benefit (which are probably obvious to someone more experienced with these things) -- First, am I right in thinking that we (by which I mean a computer) could do series reversion for the $O(\epsilon^n)$ expansion for each $n$, and thus get an asymptotic series for $x_*$? This is probably nasty for this specific problem, but I'm interested in the principle of the thing.

Comment: Secondly and relatedly, can we get big-oh bounds on the error of this approximation during th series reversion step? That is, can we say $x_* = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{r}{\log 2} + \epsilon(r) + O(f(r))$, where $f(r)$ is some function like $1/r$, etc. Again, this is probably obvious to experts, but I would love to know

Comment: @HallaSurvivor. You are right and I shall try to do something in this spirit for you. But I think that my new answer is more promising.

Answer (score 1):

*I prefer to add a second answer since the approach is quite different.*

Let $x=\frac{y}{y-1}$ and consider that we look for the zero of function
$$f(y)=y^r+(y-1)^r-2$$ which is more pleasant since $f(1)=-1$ and $f(2)=2^r-1$ which show that the solution is close to $1^+$.

The initial guess, taken from the first answer, is
$$y_0=\frac{2 r+\log (2)}{2 r-\log (2)}$$ Trying to improve as before
$$y_1=\frac{2 r+\log (2)}{2 r-\log (2)}-\frac 1r\, \frac{\left(\frac{2\log (2)}{2 r-\log (2)}\right)^r+\left(\frac{2 r+\log (2)}{2
   r-\log (2)}\right)^r-2}{\left(\frac{2 \log (2)}{2 r-\log
   (2)}\right)^{r-1}+\left(\frac{2 r+\log (2)}{2 r-\log (2)}\right)^{r-1}}$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
r & y_0 & y_1 &\text{solution} \\
 10 & 1.07180322831922 & \color{red}{1.07177346}625573 &  
                                     1.07177346253610 \\
 20 & 1.03526851583585 & \color{red}{1.035264923}95977 & 
                                     1.03526492384138 \\
 30 & 1.02337494396036 & \color{red}{1.02337389}201245 & 
                                     1.02337389199677 \\
 40 & 1.01748013332815 & \color{red}{1.01747969210}642 & 
                                     1.01747969210269 \\
 50 & 1.01395970491221 & \color{red}{1.01395947979}125 & 
                                     1.01395947979003 \\
 60 & 1.01161957027915 & \color{red}{1.01161944030}242 & 
                                     1.01161944030192 \\
 70 & 1.00995137233426 & \color{red}{1.009951290618}34 & 
                                     1.00995129061812 \\
 80 & 1.00870203846592 & \color{red}{1.00870198379052} & 
                                     1.00870198379052 \\
 90 & 1.00773140758048 & \color{red}{1.00773136921722} &  1.00773136921722 \\
 100 & 1.00695557800201 & \color{red}{1.00695555005676} &  1.00695555005676
\end{array}
\right)$$ and, if required, better could be still done. For example, adding a second term is the expansion, for $r=10$, we have
$y=\color{red}{1.071773462536}75$ to be compared to the exact solution
$y=\color{red}{1.07177346253610}$.